# Alfred toggles very slowly

Tags: leopard, alfred

On a `MacBook5,2` running `OSX 10.5`, with only `2GB RAM`, [Alfred](http://www.alfredapp.com/) toggles *very* slowly, like up to 5 seconds after the keystroke.
After I've *just* toggled it, it will toggle again much faster, but after a while it will be slow again.
What can I do to identify and fix the problem?

IIRC it does that even with the computer just started, so it's unlikely it's already swapping, but I'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd recommend turning off fade-in animation under Appearance where you'll see "Fade in Alfred window".

The only reasons Alfred would be slow are either RAM swapping and you're out of memory or, unlikely but possible, could be due to a network drive that is still being looked for after being disconnected.

Comment: Just for everyone's information, Vero is from the Alfred team, so I'd say she knows what she's talking about :)

Comment: Disabling the fade-in helped a lot. Now it still takes a few odd moments to load (on my other Mac it's instant), but since it's <1s I don't mind. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Look on the features pane of the Alfred preference window. Untick any unnecessary options.  That should speed Alfred up.